# How can I create a datepicker using kendo UI core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I downloaded Kendo UI Core, then included the kendo.ui.core.min.js and kendo.bootstrap.min.css files. Added the bundles etc.. So I was trying to create a datepicker doing this

```
<input class='k-widget k-calendar' id='StartingDate'></input>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function () {
      $('#StartingDate').kendoDatePicker();
  })
</script>
```

but it is not working.  The method kendoDatePicker() doesn't exist.  I looked through the JS and it looked they were using DateView, but that didn't work either.  Is there a different method, or am I missing something to make this work?

Comment: in what order did you include jQuery and kendo.ui.core? jQuery has to be loaded first

Comment: Yea jquery is being loaded first <link href="/Content/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

        <script src="/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>

Comment: since I'm seeing the "MVC" tag, I assume you're using VS - are you sure you don't have jQuery included twice, once at the end of the page / layout from the VS template?

Comment: Yeah it is at the bottom as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you include jQuery before `kendo.ui.core` (so Kendo UI can set up the widgets in `$.kendoWidgetName`) and that you're only including jQuery once (so the `$` variable Kendo UI set itself up in isn't overwritten).

Comment: Thanks Lars, do you know why the default template would include jquery twice?

Comment: I think you may have included it yourself when you added the Kendo UI files, and the other one is created via something like this @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") at the end of the _Layout file

Comment: It's possible. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I have exactly the same setup and had the same problem. But doing all these steps I still get the following JavaScript error message: kendoDatePicker is not a function. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. I accidentally included kendo.core.min.js instead of kendo.ui.core.min.js

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly you could probably do without the class on the input.  I believe the kendo.ui.core will add the classes.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that the classes can be omitted.

Comment: @Jenny Yeah, it's a bit unfortunate that Telerik chose to call their OSS version "Core" which is the source of this confusion. kendo.core.min.js contains reusable code that is not ui-specific (used in both OSS and professional), while kendo.ui.core contains all of the code for the OSS version, including kendo.core.min.js (I think).